# String returns number instead of text?

Tags: android

my problem is that when a single checkbox is checked it shows the text it is supposed to.
But when both checkboxes are checked it only shows the text of the second one.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView text;
    CheckBox firstCheck, secondCheck;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        secondCheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view) {
        if(firstCheck.isChecked()) {
            text.setText(R.string.checkbox_1);
        }
        if(secondCheck.isChecked()) {
            text.setText(R.string.checkbox_2);
        }
        if(firstCheck.isChecked()==false && secondCheck.isChecked()==false) {
            text.setText(R.string.unchecked);
        }
    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Les 2_1</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="checkbox_1">Checkbox 1 </string>
    <string name="checkbox_2">Checkbox 2</string>
    <string name="button_1">Click here!</string>
    <string name="textview_2">And?</string>
    <string name="unchecked">No buttons checked!</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: well of course its going to, you overwrite the text when it passes `secondCheck`

Comment: Also firstCheck.isChecked()==false is redundant, use !firstCheck.isChecked()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(firstCheck.isChecked()) {
    text.setText(R.string.checkbox_1);
}
if(secondCheck.isChecked()) {
    text.setText(R.string.checkbox_2);
}
```

If the the if's are both entered, the 2nd setText overrides the text of the first.

You can solve this by appending text

```
Resources res = getResources();
text.setText(text.getText().toString() + res.getString(R.string.checkbox_x));
```

or adding an if that covers both

```
if (firstCheck.isChecked() && secondCheck.isChecked()) {
    text.setText(res.getString(R.string.checkbox_1) + res.getString(R.string.checkbox_2));
}
```

Comment: text.setText(R.string.checkbox1 + R.string.checkbox2); won't work because R.string.checkbox1 and 2 are returning int values! So, you are accessing the wrong resource (if it exists)!

Comment: @haywire I just focussed on the issue in the question.. can't check everything ;-)

Comment: It's ok but please correct it then since it won't work.

Comment: Your edit was rejected cause of a conflict, you can try again now

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
if(secondCheck.isChecked()) {
            text.setText(R.string.checkbox_2);
        }
```

Is overwriting the text so you need to append the checkbox_2 text, not just set it.